# DESC not working in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to execute DESCRIBE query to view database table, but i am not able to as it shows error 'Incorrect syntax the keyword DESC'

Query :

DESC 'table-name'

Comment: What does a DESCRIBE query mean? Show us your query.

Comment: You cannot use Oracle commands on SQL Server and hope they will work

Comment: Part of the reason for the downvotes is that you do not appear to have made basics searches for your answer. Instead, you could improve the question by restating as `how do you describe an object in SQL Server. you’re familiar with the Oracle syntax of DESCRIBE and tried that but of course it doesn’t work. How can this be accomplished in SQL Server?`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `sp_help` to get what you want. This is SQL Server, not Oracle.

```
use yourDB;
exec sp_help 'yourTable';
```

[sp_help (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> **Reports information** about a database object (any object listed in the
>   sys.sysobjects compatibility view), a user-defined data type, or a
>   data type.

This `sp` only reads table `metadata`, it does not modify anything.

Comment: I did found this possible solution but i am afraid tha EXEC command will execute procedure calls and do some modification.

Comment: So in your opinion any stored procedure must MODIFY something??? This is wrong, any piece of code can be written as sp, for example CREATE DBO.SP_HI AS SELECT 'HI!'

Comment: @Darshana you would greatly Benefit by checking out articles that highlight high-level differences between Oracle and SQL server such as the one from [TechDifferences](https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-oracle-and-sql-server.html)